# Importing a variable from another file in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, import

I have two files - *abc.py* and *main.py*. My aim is to import the whole dictionary from another file. To explain it better, a user enters a input(lets say English) and this should be import variable English from the *abc.py* into *main.py*. Below is the code I tried, it's giving me an error.

*/abc.py

```
English = {1:"Hello", 2:"World"}
Italian = {1:"Bonjour", 2:"Mondo"}
```

*/main.py

```
import abc
option=input("Please Enter 'English' or 'Italian': ")
selectedLanuage = abc.option

print(selectedLanuage)
```

Comment: The error occurs because option is stored as a string and you can't do abc."English" it needs to be abc.English

Comment: Can you also post the error you're seeing?

Comment: @Bond0008 how do I solve that?

Comment: @kingkupps
 AttributeError: module 'abc' has no attribute 'option'

Answer (score 0):

One workaround I can think of is separating the access of the dictionary and the input.

```
option=input("Please Enter 'English' or 'Italian': ")
if option == "English":
    selectedLanguage = abc.English
elif option == "Italian":
    selectedLanguage = abc.Italian
print(selectedLanguage)
```

EDIT:

```
languages = {"English": abc.English, "Italian": abc.Italian}
option = input("Please Enter 'English' or 'Italian': ")
selectedLanguage = languages[option]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want to void

Comment: One other thing I thought of was having a dictionary of dictionaries that initially defines the language strings to the corresponding dictionaries but I am not sure it that will be viable in your circumstances.

Comment: And the absolute last resort that I shouldn't mention is using eval()

Answer (score 0):

First, I highly recommend you name your current `abc` file something else since `abc` is actually a [standard library module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html). Assuming you have the following in `languages.py`

```
English = {1: "Hello", 2: "World"}
Italian = {1: "Bonjour", 2: "Mondo"}
```

and the following in `main.py`

```
from languages import English, Italian

languages_by_choice = {
    'English': English,
    'Italian': Italian
}

option = input('Please enter "English" or "Italian": ')
selected_language = languages_by_choice.get(option)
if not selected_language:
    raise ValueError('Invalid language selection: {}'.format(option))

print(selected_language)
```

your program would be used something like this:

```
~ python3 main.py   
Please enter "English" or "Italian": English
{1: 'Hello', 2: 'World'}

~ python3 main.py
Please enter "English" or "Italian": Italian
{1: 'Bonjour', 2: 'Mondo'}

~ python3 main.py
Please enter "English" or "Italian": asdf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stackoverflow.py", line 11, in <module>
    raise ValueError('Invalid language selection: {}'.format(option))
ValueError: Invalid language selection: asdf
```